# How do I add a google cloud endpoints client library to a yeoman generated angular app?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, google-cloud-endpoints

I have generated a angular app using `yo angular`. I then add the `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init">
</script>` and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init(){
      window.init();
    }
</script>
```

to the generated index.html. In the generated controller I add

```
$window.init= function() {
        $scope.$apply($scope.loadScoreboardLib);
    };
$scope.loadScoreboardLib = function() {
    var ROOT = 'https://id.appspot.com/_ah/api';
    gapi.client.load('name', 'v1', function() {
        $scope.isBackendReady = true;
        $scope.list();
    }, ROOT);
};
```

But when saving the file I get gapi not defined. Have I placed the code in the wrong place or what is the problem? I see that gapi isn't declared but viewing some examples it seems as no one is declaring it explicitly, so I just assumed it was google magic or the lack of knowledge I have.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?